# Conditional Probability in Distribution Functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

I am having trouble in figuring out part c and d.

**For part c**:

What I did was I added `(1.5 / 8) + (1 - (4/16)) + 1` This is because `Y >= 1.5` goes through the last three equations in F(y) but the answer I got was incorrect.

**For part d**:

It would be `[P(Y >= 1) and P(Y <= 3)] / P(Y <= 3)` so that would just equal `P(Y >= 1) / P(Y <= 3)`. That would be `(1/8) + (9 / 16)` since I found F(1) / F(3). This was incorrect as well.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't you allowed to do $P(X>1.5)=1-P(X<1.5)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part c:

$$\Pr(Y\ge y)=1-\Pr(Y < y)=1-F(y)$$

For part d, assuming $y_1<y_2$:
$$\Pr(Y\ge y_1|Y\le y_2)=1-\Pr(Y < y_1|Y\le y_2)=1-\frac{\Pr(Y <y_1)}{\Pr(Y <y_2)}=1-\frac{F(y_1)}{F(y_2)}$$

Comment: Ok part c I got the correct answer I am still a little confused on part d. When you do: Pr(Y ≥ 1 | Y ≤ 3) = 1− Pr (Y < 1 | Y ≤ 3). Should it actually be 1− Pr (Y < 1 | Y > 3)? Not ≤ 3? Since you are doing 1 - ...

Comment: You should notice that the complement rule for conditional probabilities is  $P(A|B)=1-P(A'|B)$.

Comment: If it were: Pr (Y ≥ y1 | Y ≥ y2) = 1 − Pr(Y < y1 | Y ≥ y2). Would this be equal to: 1− [ F(y1) /(1 - F(y2) ]?

Comment: Remember $$\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$$ So assuming $y_1,y_2$, given $Y\ge y_2$ we are sure that $Y>y_1$ also hold and $\Pr(A\cap B)=P(B)$. Therefore, $$\Pr(Y\ge y_1|Y\ge y_2)=1$$ You can also investigate the probability of complementary event is zero since $ \Pr(A'\cap B)=0$.